# SLURM batch array loop?

Tags: bash, loops, slurm

I'm somewhat bash challenged and trying to send a large job array through slurm on my institution's cluster. I am way over my limit (which appears to be 1000 jobs per job array) and am having to iteratively parse out the list into blocks of 1000, which is tedious:

```
sbatch --array=17001-18000 -p <server-name> --time=12:00:00 <my-bash-script>
```

How might I write a loop to do this? Each job takes about 11 minutes, so I would need to build in a pause in the loop. Otherwise, I suspect SLURM will reject the new batch job. Anyone out there know what to do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not do `sbatch -a 1-50000%1000`? This would do 50000 tasks while limiting the scheduler to 1000 concurrently.

Comment: Thank you I'L'I - I should have mentioned that I did try that as per the Harvard slurm guide, but no luck. I get this error: `sbatch: error: Slurm temporarily unable to accept job, sleeping and retrying`

Comment: What do you get when you try `squeue | wc -l`? You'll want to set your array to that number and then try like the example above.

Comment: Thanks again! I'm using the loop below now (takes a day or so to run) and will try this and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do what you want

```sh
START=1
END=10000
STEP=1000
SLEEP=700 #Just over 11 Minutes (in seconds)

for i in $(seq $START $STEP $END) ; do
    JSTART=$i
    JEND=$[ $JSTART + $STEP - 1 ] 
    echo "Submitting with ${JSTART} and ${JEND}"
    sbatch --array=${JSTART}-${JEND} -p <server-name> --time=12:00:00 <my-bash-script>
    sleep $SLEEP
done
```

Comment: Thank you tomgalpin - this looks like it. I saved this as Job_loop.sh and added the shebang `#!/bin/bash` to the first line. Sorry to be slow, but when I run this with `sh Job_loop.sh` I get an error: `Job_loop.sh: line 8: JSTART: command not found
Job_loop.sh: line 9: JEND: command not found`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you very much! Just in case someone else tries this - you just need to switch the order of the sequence to `$START $STEP $END` and you can subtract 1 from `JEND` so that the sequence doesn't overlap.

Comment: No problem, sorry for the order issue with the seq command, ive updated. Happy to help